# How to set dynamic positions to the node axis in visjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vis.js, vis.js-network

I have bulk of nodes around 500 and I want to place nodes together. To achieve this I need to set the X-axis and Y-axis positions to these nodes dynamically. How do I do that in vis.js?

Comment: Suggest what? An algorithm to set the nodes position together? D:

Comment: Yes or any logic in visjs network where i can club nodes based on attribute .

Answer (score 0):

You can set nodes' coordinates using `VisData` and `update` if you set them like this:

```
// data is your data in form of { nodes:nodes, edges:edges }
window.testNodes = new vis.DataSet(data.nodes); // make it globally available for this demo
window.testEdges = new vis.DataSet(data.edges); // if you need to change something about edges too
data = { nodes: window.testNodes, edges: window.testEdges };

network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

and then use

```
window.testNodes.update({id:5,label:'wow',x:100,y:-200})
```

to update the node with `id == 5`. The `x:100,y:-200` updates coordinates, of'course.

As for putting nodes together, you should clarify what does "together" mean. For instance, you can create a simple grid and put nodes into it (by setting their coordinates like shown above). What distances do you expect from "together"? What else do you need? I'd say this deserves a separate question if you have problems not only with applying coordinates dynamically.